# How can I make animal teeth look MUCH more demonic?

Tags: demons

I'm trying to design my interpretation of Hellbound FNAF animatronics to be as terrifying as possible, and one of those methods is making their teeth, and claws be inspired by, heavily based off of, and over all just be VASTILY more satanic versions of animal teeth (more satanic version of grizzly bear teeth for Freddy for example).

But an aspect for demon teeth is to be as razor sharp as possible and while that IS terrifying I want to remain as faithful to their real world animal counter parts as possible (for example, keeping the general shape of the molars, Canines etc).

So does anyone have any tips on how I can make the animal's teeth as razor sharp as possible while keeping their general shape?

Edit Reason: someone wanted to know what im talking about

I want it to be [this](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/grizzly-bear-arctos-ursus-closeup-27227267.jpg) with the sharpness of [this](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/aliens/images/4/42/A-Quiet-Place-Alien-Monster.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20180909002747)

Comment: Welcome JB. Could you provide a link or better still a picture of what you might be referring to. On searching, I've found 4 different reference to Hellbound (live action, not animation - as there wouldn't be animatronics in animation), nothing for FNAF, and can't tell what you've got in mind. A picture would be great.

Comment: It depends. Pointy and irregular are probably the right answer.

Comment: Hav eyou ever seen a demon?  If so, what did his teeth look like?

Comment: Some things important to consider: are these teeth meant to be functional? If so is the creature in question meant to work as a carnivore? What elements specifically are you seeking with "terrifying" (something very lethal? something that probes at instinctive tendencies? A mix of both? Teeth structured like the legs of a centipede are great for shock value, but not so much for slicing meat or crushing plant matter)? This SE can be bit nitpicky in terms of being Able to define what a best answer should include, so adding in clarification for these questions would be great.

Comment: @ARogueAnt FNaF and animatronics? That's surely [Five Nights at Freddy's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Nights_at_Freddy%27s), an horror-game(s) with human-sized bear, chicken and fox animatronics (for the main characters). I don't know any "hellbound" character in this series, though, so... Two rows of teeth, big chainsaw-like teeth, you see the gist of what jaw you can expect x).

Comment: I see, then Freddy would be .. a reference to the Kruger of that name (but obliquely enough to not be trademark infringement~) @Tortliena

Comment: what are asking ? how ot change the shape without changing the shape?

Answer (score 5):

**Use actual knives.**

[image: bear with scalpels]

The FNAF monsters are built things.  You want razor sharp teeth, use razors for teeth.  I pasted in some scalpels for this bear's teeth but you could use Xacto knives, Gerber knives or whatever sharp metal you like.

[image: blades]

I think an animatronic with a mouth full of razor wire would be creepy.  Random pieces of metal (spoons, screwdrivers, brackets etc) each sharpened to an edge would be creepy.  A mouth full of shrapnel could be creepy.

[image: shrapnel]

https://www.reddit.com/r/mildlyinteresting/comments/klzbki/oc_my_great_uncles_piece_of_shrapnel_he_brought/

Comment: The bear picture is sooooooooo good.